# Работа js в php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы данный код работал? Если вставлять через консоль, все работает

```html
<?php
require 'connect.php';
mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' );
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do
{
 printf ("<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(function(){ 
$('#mydiv').text('Номер телефона: ' + 
($('#cp_id_626').text().indexOf('" .$row['name'] . "') != -1 ? '".$row['email'] ."' : '+77777777')); 
});
</script>"
 );
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
         ?>
```